# Remove Item from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` suppose `list`, and it has 8 items A-H and now I want to delete 1,3,5 position Item stored in int array from the `list` how can I do this.

I am trying to do this with

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
list.add("E");
list.add("F");
list.add("G");
list.add("H");

int i[] = {1,3,5};

for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
    list.remove(i[j]);
}
```

But after first item deleted positioned of array is changed and in the next iterate it deletes wrong element or give exception.

Comment: How about removing it in the descending order of indices (sort the indices, then removing the element with the highest index first)?

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Surely you shouldn't be thinking about the position of each item but instead thinking about the items themselves. In other words, you don't want to remove positions 1, 3 & 5 but instead you want to remove the items (wherever they are in the `List`) using `equals("B")`, `equals("D")` and `equals("F")`. Think about it.

Comment: Yes I want to delete the Item but how can I match Items. Actually in real this items are in ListView and on select I want to delete this from DB and Array and refresh adapter and List

Comment: Slow option: iterate once adding the elements to a second list, iterate the second list removing from the first (optional step: return the second list to the caller)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

*In this specific case*, you should remove the elements in descending order. First index `5`, then `3`, then `1`. This will remove the elements from the list without undesirable side effects.

```
for (int j = i.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    list.remove(i[j]);
}
```

Comment: The OP's ArrayList contains `String`s, not `Integer`s (nonetheless, I agree with your observation).

Comment: @Alex : This answer will work but it is as flawed as the OP's logic in their question. We're talking about `ArrayList<E>` - why would anyone want to remove an object from an `ArrayList` based purely on position instead of testing what's at that position? The OP may well be using `String` as the object type for the `ArrayList` but your answer is really bad coding practice for generics even if it does solve the OP's particular situation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But the OP asked about `ArrayList<String>`, not `ArrayList<E>`.

Comment: I am completely disagree with this answer, @MisterSquonk ya convinced, solution must be generic. Moreover why I am getting downvote?

Comment: @Tim : Which part of `<E>` do you not understand? My point is that when removing any object from a list/collection purely based on position (particularly if it's not sorted) without 'testing' for what is at that position is seriously bad coding practice.

Comment: @hotveryspicy : You have the closest answer as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: OK, listen... I don't know what the big deal is. The OP posted his code and I responded with an answer that illustrated a possible fix. I'm sorry I didn't go above and beyond by giving a completely general solution... but as far as I can tell, the OP wasn't asking for a programming lesson. He was asking "why is this code not working?" Don't start blaming me for down-voting your answer just because you interpreted the question differently.

Comment: if you have custom object, How you can do ?

Answer (score 30):

You can remove elements from `ArrayList` using `ListIterator`,

```
ListIterator listIterator = List_Of_Array.listIterator();

 /* Use void remove() method of ListIterator to remove an element from List.
     It removes the last element returned by next or previous methods.
 */
listIterator.next();

//remove element returned by last next method
listIterator.remove();//remove element at 1st position
listIterator.next();
listIterator.next();
listIterator.remove();//remove element at 3rd position
listIterator.next();
listIterator.next();
listIterator.remove();//remove element at 5th position
```

Comment: Its better and good practice to use ListIterator remove() method for removing objects from Collection in Java, because there may be chance that another thread is modifying the same collection and could leads to ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 10):

```
 public void DeleteUserIMP(UserIMP useriamp) {
       synchronized (ListUserIMP) {
            if (ListUserIMP.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("user is empty");
        }  else {
            Iterator<UserIMP> it = ListUserIMP.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                UserIMP user = it.next();
                if (useriamp.getMoblieNumber().equals(user.getMoblieNumber())) {
                    it.remove();
                    System.out.println("remove it");
                }
            }
            // ListUserIMP.remove(useriamp);

            System.out.println(" this user removed");
        }
        Constants.RESULT_FOR_REGISTRATION = Constants.MESSAGE_OK;
        // System.out.println("This user Deleted " + Constants.MESSAGE_OK);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned before

```
iterator.remove()
```

is maybe the only safe way to remove list items during the loop.

For deeper understanding of items removal using the iterator, try to look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993356/how-iterators-remove-method-actually-remove-an-object)

Comment: I m daze no up votes, I am totally agree with you. This is a safest way to do so.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the array i is ascend sorted, here is another solution with Iterator, it is more generic:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
list.add("E");
list.add("F");
list.add("G");
list.add("H");

int i[] = {1,3,5};

Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
int pos = 0;
int index = 0;
while( itr.hasNext() ){
    itr.next();
    if( pos >= i.length ){
        break;
    }
    if( i[pos] == index ){
        itr.remove();
        pos++;
    }

    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] mString = new String[] {"B", "D", "F"};

for (int j = 0; j < mString.length-1; j++) {
        List_Of_Array.remove(mString[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Just give it a thought-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Solution
{
        public static void main (String[] args){

             ArrayList<String> List_Of_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
             List_Of_Array.add("A");
             List_Of_Array.add("B");
             List_Of_Array.add("C");
             List_Of_Array.add("D");
             List_Of_Array.add("E");
             List_Of_Array.add("F");
             List_Of_Array.add("G");
             List_Of_Array.add("H");

             int i[] = {1,3,5};

             for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
                 List_Of_Array.remove(i[j]-j);
             }

             System.out.println(List_Of_Array);

        }


}
```

And the output was-

```
[A, C, E, G, H]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way,

```
ArrayList<String> List_Of_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
List_Of_Array.add("A");
List_Of_Array.add("B");
List_Of_Array.add("C");
List_Of_Array.add("D");
List_Of_Array.add("E");
List_Of_Array.add("F");
List_Of_Array.add("G");
List_Of_Array.add("H");

int i[] = {5,3,1};

for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
    List_Of_Array.remove(i[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use "=", a replica is created for the original arraylist in the second one, but the reference is same so if you change in one list , the other one will also get modified. Use this instead of "="

```
        List_Of_Array1.addAll(List_Of_Array);
```

Answer (score 2):

remove(int index) method of arraylist removes the element at the specified position(index) in the list. After removing arraylist items shifts any subsequent elements to the left.

Means if a arraylist contains {20,15,30,40}

I have called the method: arraylist.remove(1)

then the data 15 will be deleted and 30 & 40 these two items will be left shifted by 1.

For this reason you have to delete higher index item of arraylist first.

So..for your given situation..the code will be..

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
list.add("E");
list.add("F");
list.add("G");
list.add("H");

int i[] = {1,3,5};

for (int j = i.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    list.remove(i[j]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you need to remove end item in list can use this code

```
 if(yourList.size() != 0){
   yourList.remove(yourList.size()-1);
 }
```

or maybe you need to remove a time after select item in list

```
if(selected){// boolean for checked add or remove
   yourList.add(position , id); // add to list by position can use your list position
}else{
   if(yourList.size() != 0){ 
   yourList.remove(position);
 }
}
```