# How Iterator's remove method actually remove an object

Tags: java, loops, collections, iterator

We all know that the safest "and probably only safe" way of removing an object from a collection while iterating it, is by first retrieving the `Iterator`, perform a loop and remove when needed;

```
Iterator iter=Collection.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Object o=iter.next()
    if(o.equals(what i'm looking for)){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

What I would like to understand, and unfortunately haven't found a deep technical explanation about, is how this removal is performed,
If:

```
for(Object o:myCollection().getObjects()){
    if(o.equals(what i'm looking for)){
        myCollection.remove(o);
    }
}
```

Will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, what does "in technical terms" `Iterator.remove()` do? Does it removes the object, breaks the loop and restart the loop?

I see in the official documentation:

> "Removes the current element. Throws `IllegalStateException` if an
>   attempt is made to call `remove()` that is not preceded by a call to
>   next( )."

The part "removes the current element", makes me think of the exact same situation happening in a "regular" loop => (perform equality test and remove if needed), but why is the Iterator loop ConcurrentModification-safe?

Comment: you can see for yourself: https://gist.github.com/kibotu/e480bd7505615a7311a6

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How exactly Iterator removes elements depends on its implementation, which may be different for different Collections. Definitely it doesn't break the loop you're in. I've just looked how ArrayList iterator is implemented and here's the code:

```
public void remove() {
    if (lastRet < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    checkForComodification();

    try {
        ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
        cursor = lastRet;
        lastRet = -1;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

So it checks for concurrent modifications, removes element using public ArrayList *remove* method, and increments counter of list modifications so ConcurrentModificationException won't be thrown at next iteration.

Comment: Index of last element returned by the iterator. It's set to -1 because this element has been just removed from the list.

Comment: My Java is a bit rusty - but what's the `ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet)`? Why is it needed to write `ArrayList.this`? Is it an inner class or something?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, this line is called from inner class (`private class Itr implements Iterator<E>`), so `this` points to the instance of `Itr` and `ArrayList.this` points to the instance of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 21):

The reason why you cannot modify a list while iterating over it is because the iterator has to know what to return for hasNext() and next().

How this is done is implementation specific, but you could have a look at the source code of ArrayList/AbstractList/LinkedList etc.

Also note that in some situations you can use some code like this as an alternative:

```
List<Foo> copyList = new ArrayList<>(origList);
for (Foo foo : copyList){
  if (condition){
    origList.remove(foo);
  }
}
```

But this code will probably run slightly slower because the collection has to be copied (shallow copy only) and the element to remove has to be searched.

Also note that if you're using the iterator directly it's recommended to use a for loop instead of while loop as this limits the scope of the variable:

```
for (Iterator<Foo> iterator = myCollection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
...
}
```