# How does modifying an iterator actually change the list it's iterating over?

Tags: java, oop, iterator

I wanted to modify a list while iterating over it but realized that's not a good practice, so I had to use the iterator, but I'm kind of surprised that modifying iterator change the underlying list..

I want to use  `item` through out the program but modify it if it contains a specific value. How does the iterator do this actually? I mean `item` is not being modified, the iterator object called `domainCDCIter` is the one that we call `.remove()` on... How would that cause `item` to be modified?

Could someone demystify this?

```
    Iterator<DomainCDC> domainCDCIter = item.getChangeList().iterator();
    while (domainCDCIter.hasNext())
    {
        // if record is populated with DELETE, we want to remove it from changeList.
        final DomainCDC domainCDC = domainCDCIter.next();
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(domainCDC.getEvent()) && domainCDC.getEvent().equals("DELETE")){
            deleteFromSearchList.add(domainCDC);
            deletableDomainCDCStatusMap.put(domainCDC.getObjectId(), domainCDC.getDomainCDCStatus());
            domainCDCIter.remove();
        } else{
            indexableDomainCDCStatusMap.put(domainCDC.getObjectId(), domainCDC.getDomainCDCStatus());
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: [Seems it has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993356/how-iterators-remove-method-actually-remove-an-object)

Comment: The Iterator has a reference to the original list, and when you call `remove` the Iterator modifies the original list for you.

Comment: How does this do it programmatically???