# ConcurrentModificationException in iterator.next() Multithreaded

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, iterator, concurrentmodification

I have created this simple worker thread to calculate palindromes by iterating through an ArrayList. 
I get an Error when I execute line temp_str1 = it.next();.
The ArrayList buffer_List is not used by any other thread hence using synchronized block does not help. I have looked through previous questions and they did not help much. I would eager to find the solution to this problem.

Here is My code:

```
private void find_Palindromes(ArrayList<String> buffer_List){
    Iterator<String> it = buffer_List.iterator();
    String temp_str1, temp_str2;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        temp_str1 = it.next();
        //System.out.println(temp_str1);
        it.remove();

        if(is_Palindrome(temp_str1)){
            to_Shared_Queue(temp_str1);
            palin_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

> Edit Code : added to_Shared_Queue

```
  private void to_Shared_Queue(String str){           
        synchronized(shared_queue){
            Shared_queue.add(str);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Your [mcve] please.

Comment: Look at this guy's answer, might help you out. It's the remove method you're using to remove the item from the ArrayList. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993356/how-iterators-remove-method-actually-remove-an-object

Comment: I bet you are modifying buffer_List in to_Shared_Queue method.

Comment: @MGorgon: that's my bet too, but who the hell really knows for sure.

Comment: @MGorgon I am only sending the string temp_str1 within the parameter of to_Shared_Queue hence the list is not modified.

Comment: Sorry, objects (anything that is not a primitive) such as lists are passed _by reference_, so there's only one copy and you are modifying the _same_ object.  See this canonical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: could you add your `to_Shared_Queue` method then? if the list is not modified there, maybe the list is still somehow accessed concurrently...

Comment: You are modifying the ArrayList somehow while iterating through it. You need to find out how, by inspecting the method that you're not showing likely.

Comment: If Shared_queue is this same list as buffer_List then you have answer what's wrong.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of you modifying iterator while looping over it . you can do it by remove it from your array  buffer_List. 
buffer_List.remove(temp_str1);

Comment: this looks to be the exact opposite of what we recommend.